# Does Apache + geoserver require double logins?

Tags: apache, geoserver

**Behaviour:**

1) I access the site, enter the userID/password that's required for the site

2) The site starts to load, but when the request is made to the WMS layers being served from the GeoServer ->

3) I get a second login-prompt that only accepts users(in this case the admin user) for the GeoServer.

Obviously,

Point 3 shouldn't be happening because i  can access the WMS-requests "standalone" without logging in, so I think that the Geoserver is correctly configured.

The apache-config is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  <Directory "/var/www">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Directory>

  ProxyPass /geoserver http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver
  ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas why the site asks for the second login-prompt, regarding the geoserver?

Comment: have you set up any security rules in GeoServer? normally you shouldn't need to log in for a WMS request. How are you making the request?

Comment: Request is made via an OpenLayers 2 client. No security rules in Geoserver that we've altered to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be similar to an issue my team has had.  If you add the same username and password combination as your apache user to your geoserver setup then it should stop prompting for the login.

Geoserver users.xml can be found in `/data/security/usergroup/default/users.xml`

Or i think you can do it through the geoserver backend.

Comment: I'll give this a shot! Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: Seems to have worked like a charm! Thanks for the solution :)